# The use of java sprintboot JAP criteriabuilder (and or)

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteriaquery

I have a question about CriteriaBuilder API. I am new in JPA, I would like to creates (and or）combination。

```
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"),title));
predicates.add( 
            cb.or(cb.between(root.get("startedAt"),startTime,endTime),
                  cb.between(root.get("endedAt"),startTime,endTime),
                  cb.and(
                        cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("endedAt").as(Date.class),endTime),
                        cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("startedAt").as(Date.class),startTime))
                    ));
```

**output results**

```
where title = ？ and (started_at between ? and ? or started_at between ? and ?  or
 ended_at>=? and started_at <=?)
```

**What I want is a result**

```
where title = ？ and (started_at between ? and ? or started_at between ? and ?  or
 (ended_at>=? and started_at <=?)
)
```

How can one achive this using CriteriaBuilder? Thank you for your advice！！！

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("title"),title),
                      cb.or(cb.or(cb.between(root.get("startedAt"),startTime,endTime),
                                  cb.between(root.get("endedAt"),startTime,endTime)),
                            cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("endedAt").as(Date.class),endTime),
                                   cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("startedAt").as(Date.class),startTime)))
                      ));
```

Comment: Tried your answer，the output is still：where title = ？ and (started_at between ? and ? or started_at between ? and ?  or
 ended_at>=? and started_at <=?)

Comment: @aaaa I changed my answer would you please check that again?